# Компиляция Xamarin.Droid

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin

Здравствуйте, столкнулся с проблемой при компиляции проекта под андроид: Error parsing XML: no element found в файле values-zu.xml

```
C:\Users\nik_borgolov\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\AppFull\AppFull\AppFull.Droid\obj\Debug\resourcecache\801315905077100BEF6EE6258C88454F\res\values-zu\values-zu.xml(2): error APT0000: Error parsing XML: no element found
```

[image: Лог ошиьки]
Из-за чего возникает такая ошибка и как её решить?

Собственно сам файл пуст:
[image: values-zu.xml]

Comment: Покажите 2 строчку файла values-zu.xml

Comment: Добавил в описание

Answer (score 0):

Файл для ресурсов не должен быть пуст. Android в зависимости от языка системы выбирает строковые ресурсы на нужном языке. Минимум, что должно быть в файле это тег

```
<resources>

</resources>
```

Если же вы не хотите делать локализацию на `zu`, тогда вообще удалите файл